# TikZ: Node at same x-coordinate as another node, but specified y-coordinate?

Tags: tikz-pgf

In TikZ, if I have a node (A), how do I create a node (B) with the same x-coordinate as (A), but a given y-coordinate?

Comment: Use the orthogonal coordinate system identifiers `-|` (vertical component of the first and horizontal component of the second) and `|-` (horizontal component of the first and vertical component of the second) . - Given y-coordinate=9: `\node (B) at (A|-9) {B};`

Answer (score 102, accepted):

You can use the `let` syntax, that allows you to save a node coordinate into a macro `\p<number>` and then access its components using `\x<number>` and `\y<number>`. This requires the `calc` library to be loaded.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\node (A) at (2,1) {A};
\path let \p1 = (A) in node  at (\x1,3) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: pgf let syntax]

Comment: IMHO you should explicit state that it needs the `calc` library. Also `positioning` would be an alternative worth mentioning, even when the `y` coordinate can only be given relatively.

Comment: @Martin: I've added the bit about the need for the `calc` library. I guess you should write an answer using the `positioning` library, it is a worthwhile alternative indeed.

Comment: Thanks for the edit. And sure I should post it as my own answer. However, I'm already on the rep-limit for today and didn't wanted to take easy earned rep points away from other people :-)

Comment: It should be noted that the let...in syntax only works locally; you can't use it if you need the coordinate in another path.

Answer (score 121):

Even simpler than the let syntax, I've lately become a fan of intersection coordinate systems; this example is technically a perpendicular intersection system (see 13.3 of the 2.10 manual).  (Code modified from Jake's answer.)

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\node (A) at (2,1) {A};
%\path let \p1 = (A) in node  at (\x1,3) {B};
\draw (A |- 52,3) node {B};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

The first coordinate supplies the x value, the second the y value.  (So it is perhaps a little counterintuitive in this particular use that "52" above is just discarded.)

Comment: Does the 52 have any effect on the bounding box?

Comment: Nice approach. @Matthew: I don't think it does.

Comment: @Matthew it doesn't, but I couldn't find anything in the documentation.

Comment: The 2.10 manual I have (TeXLive) does not have a section 12.2.4. The closest I found was section 13.3 *Coordinates at Intersections*.

Comment: @Martin you are right, looks like I had the old manual for 2.0 on this computer.

Comment: This is a good solution @kgr. Note that if you want y-coordinate, use :
`\draw (1, 52 |- A) node {B};`

Comment: One can use a command to abstract this a bit if it seems unintuitive: `\newcommand{\combineXY}[2]{#1 |- #2}`.

Comment: Since the x-value of the y-giving coordinate is arbitrary, perhaps it is better to just omit it. This works: `\draw (A |- , 3) node {B};`.

Answer (score 36):

Another option, you can place nodes using shift. Here you have some examples.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\node (A) at (2,1) {A};
\path ([yshift=2cm]A) node {B};
\node (C) at ([yshift=1cm]A) {C};
\node (D) at ([shift=({1cm,1cm})]A) {D};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: The `([shift=({1cm,1cm})]A)` is best and is the only one I could understand of all the other answers given.

Answer (score 27):

The `let` syntax already shown in Jakes answer is the most flexible one IMHO. However if you want to simple place a node above or below another (or left or right of it) you can use the `above of=<node>` or `below of=<node>` options. The `positioning` library gives you even more options like `above=<opt.length> of <node>` etc.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (1,3) {A};
\node [below=2cm of A] {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I guess it is worth pointing out that `below=<distance> of` will make the *gap* between the nodes equal `<distance>`, unlike the other solutions suggested so far, which make the *distance between the centres* equal a specified distance. This behaviour can be achieved with the positioning library by specifying `on grid` before the `below` option.

Answer (score 27):

Another answer

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
  \tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
  \edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
  \edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

%
\begin{document}
%
\begin{tikzpicture}
%Define some point A 
\coordinate (A) at (1,1);
%
%Get x and y coordinates of point A
\gettikzxy{(A)}{\ax}{\ay}
%
%Using x coordinate of point A, define point B
\coordinate (B) at (\ax,4);
\fill[blue] (A) circle (2pt) node [black,right] {A};
\fill[red] (B) circle (2pt) node [black,right] {B};;
%
\end{tikzpicture}
%
\end{document}
```

[image]

> Red dot is the new point with same x coord of blue dot and some y coord.

Comment: This looks like a nice and easy solution, but on Kubuntu 14.04 (with pgf 2.10-1) I get the error message that \pgfutil is an undefined control sequence.

Answer (score 15):

Besides Jake's suggestion, you could also use `chains` (requires the `chains` library), or relative positioning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{chains}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}%[every node/.style={draw}]
\draw [help lines] (0,-2) grid (4,2);
% using explicit coordinates to place the nodes
  \node (A) at (0,0) {A};
  \node (B) at (0,2) {B};
% using relative positioning 
  \node[below=of A] (C) {C};
% using chains 
  \begin{scope}[xshift=3cm,start chain=going below,node distance=5mm]
    \node[on chain] {D};
    \node[on chain] {E};
  \end{scope}
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your comment! Interesting approach, I didn't know about that library. Accepted the other answer, though, as it was a shorter solution.

Answer (score 6):

Another way based on `\usetikzlibrary{calc}` (alternative to Jake's syntax):

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (4,4);
\node (A) at (2,1) {A};
\node (B) at ($(A)+(0,2)$) {B};
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Same output:

[image]