# Shift line connecting anchors

Tags: tikz-pgf

How can I shift a line the endpoints of which are defined by anchors like this?

```
\draw (i0) -- (i1);
```

The following approach does not work:

```
\draw[xshift=2pt] (i0) -- (i1);
```

Comment: The question are ambiguous. You write anchors like anchors of node (tikz's notion) or you use another definition. I would like to know if anchors are coordinate `\coordinate (i0) at (A.north west);` or if anchors are nodes like in Marco's answer because the answer is not the same

Answer (score 63, accepted):

**Approach 1**

You can work with the library `calc`:

```
\draw[green] (i0) -- ($(i1)+(1,2)$);
```

**Approach 2**

Another approach based on the `let` operation. An example is given in the question [TikZ: Node at same x-coordinate as another node, but specified y-coordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate)

```
\draw[blue] let \p1 = (i0) in (2,\y1) -- (i1);
```

**Approach 3**

[Jake](https://tex.stackexchange.com/users/2552/jake) mentioned another approach. You set the shift to the coordinate directly. (this method is documented in the manual section 13 "Specifying Coordinates")

```
\draw ([xshift=2pt]i0) -- ([xshift=2pt]i1);
```

Note: By using this method will work fine if you define `i0` and `i1` with `\coordinate`. If you define `i0` and `i1` with `\node` you must give an anchor

```
\draw ([xshift=2pt]i0.center) -- ([xshift=2pt]i1.center);
```

This limitation isn't relevant for the other approaches.

**Complete example with result**

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\verb+Calc+
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (i0){};
\node at (2,2) (i1){};
\draw[red] (i0) -- (i1);
\draw[blue] ($(i0)+(2,0)$) -- (i1);
\draw[green] (i0) -- ($(i1)+(1,2)$);
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb+let+
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (i0){};
\node at (2,2) (i1){};
\draw[red] (i0) -- (i1);
\draw[blue] let \p1 = (i0) in (2,\y1) -- (i1);
\draw[green] let \p1 = (i1) in (i0) -- (\x1,4);

\draw[black] let \p0 = (i0), \p1=(i1) in (\x0,2) -- (\x1,3);
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb+shift+ 1
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node at (0,0) (i0){};
\node at (2,2) (i1){};
\draw[red] (i0) -- (i1);
\draw[blue]([xshift=2cm]i0.center) --  (i1);
\draw[green] (i0) -- ([yshift=2cm,xshift=1cm]i1.center);
\end{tikzpicture}

\verb+shift+ 2
\begin{tikzpicture}
\coordinate (i0) at (0,0) ;
\coordinate (i1) at (2,2) ;
\draw[red] (i0) -- (i1);
\draw[blue]([xshift=2cm]i0) --  (i1);
\draw[green] (i0) -- ([yshift=2cm,xshift=1cm]i1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: A different approach would be to add the transformation to the coordinate specification (so `\draw ([xshift=2pt]i1) -- ([xshift=2pt]i2);`). Maybe you could flesh out your answer to show examples for all three approaches?

Comment: I just tried the experiment and found that the syntax `([shift={(1,2)}]A)` only works for positioning **nodes**.  Strangely, `([shift={(1,2)}]0,0)` works for arbitrary paths.  I have no idea why this would be so, it seems rather illogical to me.

Comment: Ah, I see that the answer has been edited and that it works if an explicit anchor is given.  This could be a bug in how the point-on-the-perimeter is computed for a translated node.  Or one could say that translating a node coordinate *without* a specific anchor is open to different interpretations on which anchor should be used, so translating without an anchor should not be used.

Comment: Good.  And I like the expanded commentary.  (Minor typo: an extra `)` in the codes in Approach 3).  Incidentally, you can specify both shifts at the same time via `[shift={(1,2)}]` (the braces protect the comma).

Comment: I think there is problem. When you write `\draw (i0)--(i1);` the line depends of the relative position of the nodes. The anchors used is not the same also when you use `([xshift=10pt]i0.center)`you are not sure that `center` is the good anchor and  with  `let \p0 = (i0)` the problem is the same because `center` are used. For me the result is not fine.

Comment: I think `i0` and `i1` must be `coordinates`,  if `i0` and `i1` are nodes then the problem is more complicated

Comment: @Altermundus: Do you think I should switch to `coordinate`?

Comment: It would be interesting to know what Jake and Andrew think about that. My english  is not evolved enough and perhaps I don't understand the question but with nodes at (0,0) and (2,2) anchors used are north east and south west. With coordinates there are no problem. How do you understand "anchors" in the question ?

Comment: @Altermundus: "Blind leading the blind" -- My english is also bad. Based on the manual I would say `anchor` is `east` or `west` and so on.

Comment: @AndrewStacey and @@Jake Have you seen the comments of @@@Altermundus? What do you think?

Comment: @Jake: note Marco's comment.  (Marco, only one notification works per comment Jake wouldn't have seen that one.  You get this one as you wrote the answer.)

Comment: @Altermundus That's what I was alluding to in my second comment.  Specifying `(-1,0) -- ([yshift=1cm]i0)` is ambiguous.  What coordinate should result?  Do we *first* compute the coordinate correct for `i0` (`west` in this example) and then shift it, or do we imagine that there is a copy of `i0` at (in this case) `(0,1)` and then compute the anchor for *that* node (`south west` in this example).  The problem isn't fully specified.  So I think that both yours and Marco's answers complement each other as it is quite possible that someone wanting to do this won't have thought about this (ctd)

Comment: @Altermundus and Marco Daniel: "anchors" are specified points on a shape, like `north east`, `base west`, `135`, and so on. If you don't supply an anchor to a coordinate specification, but only a node name (like `i0`), an anchor on the edge the node that lies in the direction of the path is used. Only if `i0` happens to be a node of the `coordinate` shape (created using `\coordinate ...` or `\node [coordinate] ...`), this is equivalent to the `center` anchor. So the original question is indeed ambiguous, as Altermundus noted. I guess it's another example of why MWEs are useful...

Comment: (ctd) until they see the possible solutions, whereupon they will decide which behaviour they want and choose accordingly.

Answer (score 10):

For me the shifting line is like the blue one

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc} 
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture} 
\draw [help lines] (0,0) grid (3,2); 
\node[draw](i0) at (0,0) {};
\node[draw](i1) at (2,2) {};
\draw[red] (i0) -- (i1) coordinate[pos=0] (j0) coordinate[pos=1] (j1); 

\draw[thick,blue] ([xshift=1cm]j0) --  ([xshift=1cm]j1);
\draw[thick,purple] let \p0=(i0),\p1=(i1) in
         ([xshift=.5cm]\x0,\y0) --  ([xshift=.5cm]\x1,\y1);        
\end{tikzpicture} 

\end{document}
```

[image]