# tikz relative coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf

Suppose one defines coordinates `a` and `b`. One may draw a line connecting these two coordinates (`\draw (a) -- (b)`). Suppose one desires to draw a line that is shifted upward 1 unit relative to `a` and `b`. A first guess is the command `\draw (a){}+(0,1) -- (b){}+(0,1)`. This command, however, connects the point `a+(0,1)` to the point `b`, presumably because addition is subsequent to the draw command. How does one obtain the desired result (drawing from `a+(0,1)` to `b+(0,1)`?

MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw[fill] (0,0) circle (2pt) coordinate (a);
 \draw[fill] (5,0) circle (2pt) coordinate (b);
 \draw (a) -- (b);
 \draw (a){}+(0,1) -- (b){}+(0,1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Edit:** How does one draw coordinates at a point shifted relative to the arithmetic average of the coordinates of two points (something akin to `\node at ($(((s1)+(s2))/2)+(0,1)$)`).

Comment: possible duplicate of [Shift line connecting anchors](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/39826/shift-line-connecting-anchors)

Comment: you can use the `calc` library and use the `([yshift=1cm]$(s1)!0.5!(s2)$)` syntax

Answer (score 94, accepted):

You can try this, using the `calc` library (See Section **13.5 Coordinate Calculations** of the pgf manual):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (b) at (0,-2);
  \node[draw=red] at (a) {a};
  \node[draw=red] at (b) {b};
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,3);
  \draw ($ (a) + (0,1) $) -- ($ (b) + (0,1) $);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

To answer the follow-up, you can use partway modifiers (Section 13.5.3 of the manual). For example, the meaning of

```
(1,2)!.75!(3,4)
```

is "the coordinate that is three quarters on the way from (1,2) to (3,4)." A little complete example:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (a) at (2,2);
  \coordinate (b) at (0,-2);
  \node[draw=red] at (a) {a};
  \node[draw=red] at (b) {b};
  \draw[help lines] (-1,-3) grid (3,3);
  \draw ($ (a) + (0,1) $) -- ($ (b) + (0,1) $);
  \draw[blue,thick] (-1,2) -- ($ (a)!0.5!(b) $) -- (3,2);
  \draw[magenta,thick] (2,-2) -- ($ (a)!0.75!(b) $) -- ($ (a)!0.25!(b) $) -- (3,2);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: +1 for explanation on '!'. I finally find it here. Thanks!

Comment: How do you divide a coordinate by a fixed amount? Do you use the "!" command?

Comment: @stars83clouds. Do it w.r.t. origin. For instance, half of coordinate (a) can be written as (a)!0.5!(0,0)

Comment: After too much work, I have finally found something about the ! in coordinates specification. Is there any official doc about the usage of the exclamation mark? I could not find anything on the manual