# How to add number in a circle?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I want to add some numbers at 3 places in Venn program. But I don't know how to do that.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
\draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: `\node at (0,0) {zero};` is for the origin (0,0). The other coordinates you can obtains using polar coordinates. For example, the center of the left circle has angle 210 and radius 1.75. If you change the angle you can pass to other points inside the white area.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Based on your tikz code, this attempt defines two internal name called B and C for the two circles and uses them as reference points where you can use many skills to place your text. For examples, `above, below, left, right= xx cm of reference points`. `above right/left, below right/left= xx cm of reference` are also at your disposal. You need `\tikzlibrary{positioning}`.

[image]

Code:

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}
\def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\draw \secondcircle node(B) [text=black,below left] {$B$};
\draw \thirdcircle node (C)[text=black,below right] {$C$};
\node[left= 1cm of B]{1};
\node[right= 1cm of C]{4};
\node[right= 1.2 cm of B]{23};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7):

Here is a way of doing it using PSTricks:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{pstricks}

\newcommand*\circB{\pscircle(2,2){2}}
\newcommand*\circC{\pscircle(4,2){2}}

\begin{document}

\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
\begin{psclip}{\circB}
 \psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = blue!60}
 \circC
\end{psclip}
\circB
\circC
\rput(1.1,2){$B$}
\rput(4.9,2){$C$}
\rput(3,2){$1,2,3,4$}
\end{pspicture}

\bigskip

\begin{pspicture}(6,4)
\begin{psclip}{}
 \psset{fillstyle = solid, fillcolor = blue!60}
 \circB
 \psset{fillcolor = white}
 \circC
\end{psclip}
\circB
\circC
\rput(1.1,2){$B$}
\rput(4.9,2){$C$}
\rput(3,2){$1,2,3,4$}
\end{pspicture}

\end{document}
```

[image: output2]

Comment: Why does the right black border around the blue area have different thickness?

Comment: @Sigur I was do to the clipping. I've change the order of the macros, and the drawing is now as it should be.

Comment: Thanks for your reply! One more question. If I just want to fill B-C, how I could I do that?

Comment: @Hinn What is `B-C`?

Comment: @Svend Tveskag B-C means B \cap \complement_C

Answer (score 6):

You can use the `calc` library to calculate relative node positions, like [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/48757/43337):

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] (B) {$B$};
\draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] (C) {$C$};
\node at ($(B)!-0.25!(C)$) {1};
\node at ($(B)!0.5!(C)$) {2,3};
\node at ($(B)!1.25!(C)+(0,.5cm)$) {4};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! One more question. If I just want to fill B-C, how I could I do that?

Comment: I will change the order or the comands: first I will fill the B circle with the desired color (`\draw[fill=yellow] ...`) and then I will _execute_ the `scope` environment (the `\clip` will overwrite the B \cap C). If you desire only B-C, then use `fill[white]` inside the `scope`.

Answer (score 4):

The `stackinset` macro allows text (or graphics) to be overlaid an existing image.  The insets can be nested.  Location of the inset is specified in figure dimensions, relative to the left/center/right and top/center/bottom of the underlying image.  In this case, I specified offsets relative the center-center of the image.

In this case, the insets are text mode, but they can be set in math mode, `\parbox`es, or anything, really.

```
\documentclass{letter}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{stackengine}
\usepackage{tikz}
\def\secondcircle{(210:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\def\thirdcircle{(330:1.75cm) circle (2.5cm)}
\begin{document}
\stackinset{c}{-2.2cm}{c}{-.25cm}{1}{%
\stackinset{c}{}{c}{}{234}{%
\stackinset{c}{2cm}{c}{0.5cm}{5}{%
\begin{tikzpicture}
\begin{scope}
\clip \secondcircle;
\fill[cyan] \thirdcircle;
\end{scope}
\draw \secondcircle node [text=black,below left] {$B$};
\draw \thirdcircle node [text=black,below right] {$C$};
\end{tikzpicture}%
}}}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for your reply! One more question. If I just want to fill (B-C), how I could I do that?

Comment: What do you mean "fill"?  My answer allows text to be positioned and overlaid upon an existing image.  If the question concerns the use of `tikz` to color fill portions of the drawing, that would require someone else's expertise to answer.

Comment: Sorry for my expression. I mean that I only want to color part B(except B \cap C).

Comment: @Hinn If I understand your question, you would like to inset text in one, not three locations.  In that case, you can delete the two unwanted `\stackinset` lines, and two of the three closing right braces (after `\end{tikzpicture}`)

Comment: It seems like the first comment is a standard one. I'm not even sure the OP has looked at the code before posting the follow-up question. `:(`