# How to align multiple line text over arrows in multiple ways?

Tags: tikz-pgf, horizontal-alignment, tikz-arrows, arrows

How can the text over arrows be aligned (with respect to arrow end and with respect to its own text justification)? For example, I have multiple lines over arrow which I want to place near left, at center, near right and at some specified distance (say 5mm) of arrow end and also to justify the text at left, right and center. Is there a better way to have multiple lines over arrow instead of using "text width" (which I am using for the time being)?

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance   = 1cm and 2cm,
        N1/.style   = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, fill=orange!10, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
        N2/.style   = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, fill=orange!10, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=4cm, align=center},      arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth}
    ]

    \node   (a1)    [N1]                                        {abc};
    \node   (a2)    [N2, right=4cm of a1]                       {def};

    \path   [draw, arrow]  ([yshift=2mm] a1.east)  coordinate (aux1) node[above right, red, text width=1cm]{going left} --  (aux1 -| a2.west);      
    \path   [draw, arrow]  ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux1) node[below left, red,  text width=1cm]{going right} -- (aux1 -| a1.east);      

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Nice MWE! Problem solved? If yes, consider accepting one of the provided answers. The same applies to some of your other questions.

Answer (score 2):

Partly based on my answer on your previous question:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta,
                positioning,
                quotes}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
\tikzset{
node distance = 1cm and 4cm,
     N/.style = {draw, rounded corners, fill=orange!10,
                 minimum height=#1, minimum width=1cm},
    ar/.style = {draw=red, thick, -Straight Barb},
every edge quotes/.append style = {font=\footnotesize,
                                   text width=2em, align=center}
        }
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a1)  [N=10mm]                {abc};
\node (a2)  [N=40mm, right=of a1]   {def};
%
\draw[ar] ([yshift= 2mm] a1.east) coordinate (aux) to["going right", near start]  (aux -| a2.west);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux) to["going  left", near start]  (aux -| a1.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a1)  [N=10mm]                {abc};
\node (a2)  [N=40mm, right=of a1]   {def};
%
\draw[ar] ([yshift= 2mm] a1.east) coordinate (aux) to["going right", near end]  (aux -| a2.west);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux) to["going  left", near end]  (aux -| a1.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}

\medskip
    \begin{tikzpicture}
\node (a1)  [N=10mm]                {abc};
\node (a2)  [N=40mm, right=of a1]   {def};
%
\draw[ar] ([yshift= 2mm] a1.east) coordinate (aux) to["going right"]  (aux -| a2.west);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux) to["going  left"]  (aux -| a1.east);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}

\end{document}
```

[image]

You can break edge label text manually, if you more liked such a solution. In this case is advisable to remove option `text width` from the `every edge quotes` style definition and add lines terminators `\\` in label text, as you can se in the following example:

```
\draw[ar] ([yshift= 2mm] a1.east) coordinate (aux) to["going\\ right"]  (aux -| a2.west);
\draw[ar] ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux) to["going\\  left"]  (aux -| a1.east);
```

For more options and details of nodes on lines (i.e. edge labels) see *TikZ & PGF manual*, section *17.10.2 The Label Option*, page 246 -- 249 (version 3.1.b).

Answer (score 2):

One different option is to use the argument `pos` into your `node` specs, with a number between 0 and 1, depending on where you want to place the node on your path. `pos=0` is for starting point, `pos=1` is for ending point, `pos=0.5` is equivalent to `midway`.
You have to draw your path, *then* to place your node (you don't have to use the `to[...]` argument, then).

Here's the result:

[image: pos on path]

And the code (only the last two lines are modified):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{arrows,shapes,positioning}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,decorations.markings}

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering  
    \begin{tikzpicture}[
        node distance   = 1cm and 2cm,
        N1/.style   = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, fill=orange!10, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm, align=center},
        N2/.style   = {rectangle, draw, rounded corners, fill=orange!10, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=4cm, align=center},      arrow/.style = {thick,-stealth}
    ]

    \node   (a1)    [N1]                                        {abc};
    \node   (a2)    [N2, right=4cm of a1]                       {def};

    \path   [draw, arrow]  ([yshift=2mm] a1.east)  coordinate (aux1) --  (aux1 -| a2.west) node[pos=0.1,above right, red,text width=1cm, align=center]{going left};      
    \path   [draw, arrow]  ([yshift=-2mm] a2.west) coordinate (aux1) -- (aux1 -| a1.east) node[pos=0.1,below left, red,  text width=1cm, align=center]{going right};      

    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}
```

Just play with the `pos` values and the `align=` option to obtain exactly what you want.