# How to use x coordinate of a point and y coordinate of other point?

Tags: tikz-pgf

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [TikZ: Node at same x-coordinate as another node, but specified y-coordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate)
>   [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz)

How to use x coordinate of a point and y coordinate of other point?
I need similar to

```
\coordinate (A) at (2,1);
\coordinate (B) at (3,0);
\coordinate (C) at (4,3);
\coordinate (D) at (5,-1);

\draw (xA,yB) -- (xC,yD);
```

Comment: You can also extract the `x` and `y` coordinates as per [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz/).

Answer (score 48):

You can use the orthogonal coordinate system identifiers `-|` and `|-`. They indicate vertical component of the first and horizontal component of the second for `-|` and vice versa for `|-`.

I have converted the `coordinate`s to `node`s to show the locations.

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
\node (A) at (2,1) {a};
\node (B) at (3,0) {b};
\node (C) at (4,3) {c};
\node (D) at (5,-1) {d};

\draw (A |- B) -- (C |- D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 20):

Here's a less convenient solution than the solution proposed by Percusse but closer to the initial demand.

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \node (A) at (2,1) {a};
    \node (B) at (3,0) {b};
    \node (C) at (4,3) {c};
    \node (D) at (5,-1) {d};

    \draw let \p{A}=(A), \p{B}=(B), \p{C}=(C), \p{D}=(D) in
    (\x{A},\y{B}) -- (\x{C},\y{D});
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

The result is exactly the same...

Comment: This should be the accepted answer since it is valid even when you are not using `\draw`.

Comment: @AntonioSesto The other answer is also valid without `\draw`...