# align node bottom edges vertically

Tags: tikz-pgf, vertical-alignment, positioning, nodes

I would like to draw a diagram with boxes of different heights such that the bottom of each box is on the same height. Additionally, I would like to connect the nodes by horizontal arrows. My approach is to use relative positioning (`positioning` library).

Here is a MWE that illustrates the problem:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{ % from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49909/78282
    flowbox/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black
    },
    stdarrow/.style={->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \node[center,flowbox] (A) {A};
    \node[flowbox,right=of A] (B) {\tikz \draw (0,0)--(0,3);};
    \draw [stdarrow] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: first version]
Note that here, the nodes are centered vertically, the arrow is as I want it.

My idea was to use the base for relative positioning:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[english]{babel}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{ % from http://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49909/78282
    flowbox/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black
    },
    stdarrow/.style={->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=1cm]
    \node[flowbox] (A) {A};
    \node[flowbox, base right=of A] (B) {\tikz \draw (0,0)--(0,3);};
    \draw [stdarrow] (A) -- (B);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image: second version]
The problem is that here, the bottom of the second box is higher than that of the first one (since it takes the text as a reference) and the arrow is not horizontal. As I said, I would like to have the bottom edges of the two boxes on the same horizontal height and the arrow starting from the vertical center of box A going horizontal to the right. How is this feasible?

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The following code should give the desired  result (comments below):

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz,pgfplots}
\usetikzlibrary{positioning}

\tikzset{ % from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/49909/78282
    flowbox/.style={
        rectangle, rounded corners, minimum width=1cm, minimum height=1cm,text centered, draw=black
    },
    stdarrow/.style={->,>=stealth}
}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2cm]
    \coordinate (A-Coord) at (0,0);
    \coordinate[right=of A-Coord] (B-Coord);
    \node[flowbox, anchor=south] (A-Node) at (A-Coord) {A};
    \node[flowbox, anchor=south] (B-Node) at (B-Coord) {\tikz \draw (0,0)--(0,3);};
    \draw [stdarrow] (A-Node.east) -- (A-Node-|B-Node.west);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Result:

[image]

Comments:

- To adjust the placing, I defined two coordinates and the node option `anchor=south` (probably there exist better solutions for this aspect).
- To force the arrow to be horizontal, I used a orthogonal coordinate system identifier `(A-Node|-B_Node.west)` (see [this answer of percusse](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/63562/40974))
- To keep the spacing, I had to adjust the node distance `[node distance=2cm]`

Comment: Very clever solution, thanks a lot! However, I need to remove the `center` option from the nodes, otherwise I get the error _"I do not know the key '/tikz/center' and I am going to ignore it. Perhaps you misspelled it."_.
No real problem though, since it is still working as intended.

Comment: @riddleculous Your right! I just removed `center` option, since it was the artefact from a first (unsuccessfull) attempt. Thanks for spotting that and mentioning that!

Comment: I have a strange follow-up problem (should I post a new question for this?). When labeling the edge of the arrow in your example using `\draw [stdarrow] (A-Node.east) edge["AB"] (A-Node-|B-Node.west);`, I get an unwanted upwards arrow tip at the start of the arrow as marked in red [here](http://imgur.com/YR2kGDd) (for this edge command, I need to load `\usetikzlibrary{quotes}`). I don't understand why this makes a difference.

Comment: problem solved: I added `tips=proper` as an option to my `stdarrow/.style`, see pgfmanual