# Draw boolean function with relative coordinates

Tags: tikz-pgf, positioning, circuitikz, logic

What I am trying to do is to connect the input of the **or gate** with "not **x_1**" in this circuit with relative coordinates. Simply a straight line from (aor1.in 1) to (not1). I thought that I could somehow get the Y-Coordinate of (aor1.in 1) but this doesn't seem to be possible. The problem is that I can't simply say "Go 4 Units to the Left" with relative coordinates because I have more components that need to be connected to exactly one line with a specific x-coordinate. Optimaly I would be able to tell circuitikz to draw a line from the output until it reaches the specific x-coordinate. Unfortunately I failed to do so. Is there a simple way?

[image]

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\draw
(0,10.3) node{$x_0$}
(2,10.3) node{$x_1$}
(4,10.3) node{$x_2$}
(6,10.3) node{$x_3$}

(1,8) node[ieeestd not port, rotate=-90] (not1) {}
(3,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not2) {}
(5,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not3) {}
(7,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not4) {}

(9,6) node[or port] (aor1) {}

(3,6.5) -- (aor1.in 1)

(0,10) -- (0,0)
(0,9) -- (1,9) -- (not1) -- (1,0)
(2,10) -- (2,0)
(2,9) -- (3,9) -- (not2) -- (3,0)
(4,10) -- (4,0)
(4,9) -- (5,9) -- (not3) -- (5,0)
(6,10) -- (6,0)
(6,9) -- (7,9) -- (not4) -- (7,0)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX. When you post a question, please provide a ["Minimal Working Example" (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/228/ive-just-been-asked-to-write-a-minimal-example-what-is-that) that starts with `\documentclass`, includes all relevant `\usepackage` commands, ends with `\end{document}` and compiles without errors, even if it does not produce your desired output.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on the answer (and explanation) found in [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/63560/how-to-use-x-coordinate-of-a-point-and-y-coordinate-of-other-point), you may change the line `(3,6.5) -- (aor1.in 1)` to `(not2 |- aor1.in 1) -- (aor1.in 1)` and it should do what (I think) you want.

MWE:

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[scale=0.8, transform shape]
\ctikzset{logic ports=ieee}
\draw
(0,10.3) node{$x_0$}
(2,10.3) node{$x_1$}
(4,10.3) node{$x_2$}
(6,10.3) node{$x_3$}

(1,8) node[ieeestd not port, rotate=-90] (not1) {}
(3,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not2) {}
(5,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not3) {}
(7,8) node[not port, rotate=-90] (not4) {}

(9,6) node[or port] (aor1) {}

(not2 |- aor1.in 1) -- (aor1.in 1)

(0,10) -- (0,0)
(0,9) -- (1,9) -- (not1) -- (1,0)
(2,10) -- (2,0)
(2,9) -- (3,9) -- (not2) -- (3,0)
(4,10) -- (4,0)
(4,9) -- (5,9) -- (not3) -- (5,0)
(6,10) -- (6,0)
(6,9) -- (7,9) -- (not4) -- (7,0)

;
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

which produces:

[image]