# extract x value from coordinate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, coordinates

maybe I'm stupid, I looked at the many examples in which somehow shows the work with the     coordinates, but I don't understand it. Simple example - I have:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
   \coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (0.3,0.5);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I would like to use x-part of my coordinate in the next \draw command, but I don't know how to simply extract it.

```
\draw[name path=my_line, gray] (**x-part of D coordinate**,0) node[below, red]{$c$} -- (0.75,1.1);
```

I hope that's my question is obvious.
Thanks!!

Comment: look up the `let` keyword

Comment: See http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate or http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz

Answer (score 33, accepted):

You can use the `let` syntax (See Section **14.15 The Let Operation** of the manual); another option (suggested by **percusse** in a comment) is to use the `|-` syntax (page 131 of the manual). An example with both possibilities:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc,intersections}

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (0.3,0.5);
  \draw[name path=my_line, gray] let \p1=(D) in (\x1,0) node[below, red] {$c$} -- (0.75,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate [label=left:$D$] (D) at (0.3,0.5);
  \draw (D |- {{(0,0)}}) node[below, red] {$c$} -- (0.75,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

Quoting from the manual:

> the meaning of `(p-|q)` is ''the intersection
> of a vertical line through p and a horizontal line through q''.

[image]

Comment: You can also use `\draw (D |- {{(0,0)}}) -- (0.75,1.1);`.

Comment: @percusse yes, you're right: I keep forgetting about this (simpler) way; I'll add it to my answer.

Comment: `\draw (D |- 0,0) -- (0.75,1.1);` works too.

Answer (score 23):

You can also adapt the solution from [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz) and invoke `\ExtractCoordinate{D}` before you need the coordinates of this point and then use `\XCoord` or `\YCoord` where you need the value.

The code below produces output identical to Gonzalo Medina's answer.

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86897/recover-scaling-factor-in-tikz
\newcommand*\getscale[1]{%
  \begingroup
    \pgfgettransformentries{\scaleA}{\scaleB}{\scaleC}{\scaleD}{\whatevs}{\whatevs}%
    \pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{sqrt(abs(\scaleA*\scaleD-\scaleB*\scaleC))}%
    \expandafter
  \endgroup
  \expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}

\makeatletter
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz
\newdimen\@XCoord
\newdimen\@YCoord
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{%
    \getscale{\@scalefactor}%
    \path [transform canvas] (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\@XCoord}{\@YCoord};%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\XCoord}{\@XCoord/\@scalefactor}%
    \pgfmathsetlength{\YCoord}{\@YCoord/\@scalefactor}%
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=2]
   \coordinate (D) at (0.3,0.5);

  \ExtractCoordinate{D}
  \fill [red] (D) circle (1pt);
  \draw[gray] (\XCoord,0) node[below, red] {$c$} -- (0.75,1.1);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Unless I am doing something wrong, this method doesn't seem to work with scaling. I.e. if we pass a parameter 'scale=0.5' to \begin{tikzpicture}, the resulting coordinates \XCoord, \YCoord seem off. I am trying to take the coordinates of a regular polygon defined as \node[draw=none, minimum size=4cm, regular polygon, regular polygon sides = 8] (a) {};
And then taking \ExtractCoordinate{a.corner 3}, for example, produces a wrong coordinate with scaling (but a correct one without scaling).

Comment: @mathreader: Solution updated to handle `scale=` issue. Thanks for pointing that out.

Answer (score 19):

For the sake of completeness and future reference, if you have a point `(a)` defined, you can define a new point `(b)` which depends on the coordinates of `(a)` using the `let` as follows:

```
\path let \p1 = (a) in coordinate (b) at (2*\x1,\y1/2);
```

Since `\coordinate` is an alias for `\path coordinate` you have to use the above code if you want to use `let` for the definition of a coordinate.