# Can I scale all line widths in a tikzpicture?

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I have some `tikzpicture`s that were designed for a4 paper and that should now be used on an a0 poster. All the coordinates in the picture can be scaled up with the option `scale=4`, but this leaves the line widths untouched.

Can I scale the line widths, even those set directly and not using styles like `thin`, in the entire `tikzpicture`? Text contained in the picture should *not* be scaled by this.

Comment: Please not that "you could just make an a4 poster and print it on a0", while being a workaround, is not an answer to this question.

Comment: Try `\def\tikz@semiaddlinewidth#1{\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{4*#1}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{4*#1}}`. It should work in most of the cases, but probably not all of them. Ti*k*Z/PGF uses a TeX dimen to store the line width, so there's no way to step in and scale the line width by some value in a TeX assignment like `\pgflinewidth=1pt`. If the above fails somewhere, then the solution will probably be to scale the line width directly in the driver code.

Answer (score 12):

This is similar to [Phelype's comment](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/515300/can-i-scale-all-line-widths-in-a-tikzpicture#comment1302976_515300) (which I see just now) but it uses the (square root of the) Jacobian of the current transformation matrix to determine the scale factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Jacobians have already been used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86897/138900
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496418 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506249/194703
\makeatletter
\tikzset{scale line widths/.style={%
/utils/exec=\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\myJacobian*0.4pt}%
\def\tikz@semiaddlinewidth##1{\pgfmathsetmacro{\my@lw}{\myJacobian*##1}%
\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{\my@lw pt}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\my@lw pt}},%
thin}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Original}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Just scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (0,1) -- (1,0);
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Scale and \texttt{scale line widths}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,scale line widths]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (1,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (0,1) -- (1,0);
 \typeout{\the\pgflinewidth}
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

(Yes, I also see that the line joins are not nice, but this is not the point of this post. ;-)

And this is a version that locally retrieves the scale factor.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Jacobians have already been used in https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/86897/138900
% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/496418 and https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506249/194703
\makeatletter
\tikzset{scale line widths/.style={%
/utils/exec=\def\tikz@semiaddlinewidth##1{%
\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\myJacobian*0.4pt}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\my@lw}{\myJacobian*##1}%
\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{\my@lw pt}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\my@lw pt}},%
thin}}
\makeatother
\begin{document}
\subsubsection*{Original}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,1);
 \begin{scope}[scale=2]
  \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Just scale}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,1);
 \begin{scope}[scale=2]
  \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\subsubsection*{Scale and \texttt{scale line widths}}
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=4,scale line widths]
 \draw (0,0) rectangle (1,1);
 \draw[thick] (0,0) -- (0,1);
 \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,1);
 \begin{scope}[scale=2]
  \draw[line width=2pt] (1,0) -- (1,0.5);
 \end{scope} 
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Man... this is amazing! I searched the whole night for something like this!