# TikZ scaling problem

Tags: tikz-pgf

I tried

```
\begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
```

as indicated in the manual but it had no effect.

Is there an alternative to achieve the desired effect?
Is there a guide to the acceptable values for scale -?

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) `[scale=0.5]` should actually work. Without seeing a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that shows what you tried, it is impossible to tell you, why `[scale=0.5]` did not wokr in your case. Therefore, please edi your question to  include such a MWE.

Comment: Maybe you want to scale something that isn't scalable without additionally applying the `transform shape` key.

Comment: In addition to the above two comments, which cover almost all typical situations, it should be mentioned that line widths to not scale when using the `scale` key. So you may either scale them explicitly, or use e.g. https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305/194703. Moreover, in some special circumstances you may rather need the the key `transform canvas={scale=0.5}` and/or `\pgflowlevelsynccm`. However, be aware that the last two options are to be used with great care and may come with severe side effects when not used in the right way.

Comment: \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
\matrix(a)[matrix of math nodes, 
row sep=5em, column sep=6em, 
text height=1.5ex, text depth=0.25ex] 
{T_{-1}\\
T_{-2} &S^2(T_{-1})\\
{ }  & S^2(T_{-1}\oplus T_{-2})&S^3(T_{-1})\\};
\path[->](a-2-1) edge node[left]{$\pa_{-1} $} (a-1-1);
\path[->>](a-2-2) edge node[above left]{$q_0$ } (a-2-1);
\path[ ->](a-3-3) edge node[above]{$m_0$} (a-2-2);
\path[ ->](a-3-2) edge node[left]{$\pa_{-1} $} (a-2-2);
\path[ ->](a-3-3) edge node[above]{$q_0$ } (a-3-2);
\end{tikzpicture}