# Create oven symbols

Tags: tikz-pgf, symbols, draw

How do I create small oven symbols in LaTeX using tikz and/or other packages?

The symbols I want to create looks like this: (The symbols with black background on the adjuster, all of them or as many as possible)

[image]

[image]

Comment: That oven could do with some cleaning.... ;-)

Comment: Please check also https://www.ctan.org/pkg/cookingsymbols

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Drawing such symbols is very simple, here are three quickly written examples.

```
\documentclass[border=3mm,tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,line cap=round]
 \draw ([yshift=2mm]120:0.4) -- (120:0.4) arc(120:420:0.4) -- ++ (0,0.2)
 foreach \X in {0,-30,...,-180} {(\X:0.5) -- (\X:0.75)};
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.9) rectangle (0.9,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick,line cap=round]
 \draw[fill,rounded corners] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to (0.5,0) to (-60:0.5) to cycle };
 \draw[line width=2mm] (-0.6,-0.6) -- (0.6,-0.6);
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.8) rectangle (0.9,0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}
\begin{tikzpicture}[ultra thick]
 \draw[fill] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to[out=10,in=170] (0.5,0) to[out=-10,in=-50] (-60:0.5) 
        to[out=130,in=-40] cycle };
 \draw circle[radius=0.7cm];
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.8) rectangle (0.9,0.8);
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

It is just tedious to produce them. BTW, there are tons of packages such as `fontawesome` that may have one or the other symbol (I did not check), just look at `texdoc symbols`.

If you want to scale them, you could use the nice `scalerel` package.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\OvenBulb{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,line cap=round]
 \draw ([yshift=2mm]120:0.4) -- (120:0.4) arc(120:420:0.4) -- ++ (0,0.2)
 foreach \X in {0,-30,...,-180} {(\X:0.5) -- (\X:0.75)};
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.95) rectangle (0.9,0.6);
\end{tikzpicture}}{AA}}
\newcommand\OvenUnderVent{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,line cap=round]
 \draw[fill,rounded corners,very thick] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to (0.5,0) to (-60:0.5) to cycle };
 \draw[line width=2mm] (-0.6,-0.6) -- (0.6,-0.6);
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.85) rectangle (0.9,0.7);
\end{tikzpicture}}{AA}}
\newcommand\OvenVent{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,line cap=round]
 \draw[fill,very thick] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to[out=10,in=170] (0.5,0) to[out=-10,in=-50] (-60:0.5) 
        to[out=130,in=-40] cycle };
 \draw circle[radius=0.7cm];
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.85) rectangle (0.9,0.85);
\end{tikzpicture}}{AA}}
\begin{document}
A \OvenBulb\ B \OvenVent\ C \OvenUnderVent
\bigskip

{\Huge A \OvenBulb\ B \OvenVent\ C \OvenUnderVent}
\end{document}
```

[image]

A somewhat more organized way of achieving the same is to define these things as pics. Then you get these symbols with `\OvenSymbol{bulb}`, i.e. do not have to worry about the names of the macros too much, and have the additional benefit of using the pics inside any `tikzpicture` when you wish to combine them.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{pics/oven/.cd,
bulb/.style={code={
\draw ([yshift=2mm]120:0.4) -- (120:0.4) arc(120:420:0.4) -- ++ (0,0.2)
 foreach \X in {0,-30,...,-180} {(\X:0.5) -- (\X:0.75)};
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.95) rectangle (0.9,0.6);}},
under vent/.style={code={ 
 \draw[fill,rounded corners,very thick] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to (0.5,0) to (-60:0.5) to cycle };
 \draw[line width=2mm] (-0.6,-0.6) -- (0.6,-0.6);
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.85) rectangle (0.9,0.7);}},
vent/.style={code={ 
 \draw[fill,very thick] foreach \X in {0,120,240} 
  {[rotate=\X] (0,0) to[out=10,in=170] (0.5,0) to[out=-10,in=-50] (-60:0.5) 
        to[out=130,in=-40] cycle };
 \draw circle[radius=0.7cm];
 \draw[rounded corners] (-0.9,-0.85) rectangle (0.9,0.85);
 }}}
\usepackage{scalerel}
\newcommand\OvenSymbol[2][]{\scalerel*{\begin{tikzpicture}[line width=3pt,line cap=round]
 \pic[#1]{oven/#2};
\end{tikzpicture}}{AA}}
\begin{document}
A \OvenSymbol{bulb}\ B \OvenSymbol{vent}\ C \OvenSymbol{under vent}
\bigskip

{\Huge \OvenSymbol{bulb}\ B \OvenSymbol{vent}\ C \OvenSymbol{under vent}}
\end{document}
```

There is much more that one could say. I recommend reading [this discussion](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/480768).

Comment: How can you make them smaller, so that they are the same size as the text?

Comment: @Vebjorn You can use `scale=<factor>` and adjust the line width by hand, or use `scale line widths` from https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305/194703.

Comment: I tried `scale=0.1` which is a suitable size. However, the square is almost a circle then, so it doesn't look the same. It looks like a fan with two circles.

Comment: @Vebjorn I added an explicit example to my answer.