# ColorADD symbols/code or other solutions for colorblind in LaTeX/TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, color, packages, accessibility

Since I got a student this year, that is unable to see colors I thought this might be a problem others ran into as well. The most obvious thing that I could think of was "How is he able to play UNO?" ... and there is a version of UNO using the color alphabet provided by [ColorADD](http://www.coloradd.net/code.asp) to help in that case.

I couldn't find any equivalent for LaTeX/TikZ that I could use in graphics (e.g. if I plot some graphs and want the students to tell me the function I usually use different colors and/or different letters. In my biology figures they are usually colored but since that doesn't work any longer I used patterns).

But these are my solutions and the system provided by ColorADD seems to be something bigger.

My question: Does anybody know an equal approach to identify/translate colors via symbols that is used commonly? Is there any other method that I could use to help a student who isn't able to see any colors at all?

PS: I ran into the work of [Paul Tol](https://personal.sron.nl/~pault/data/colourschemes.pdf) but this only seems to help if there is a red- or green-blind-vision. For my student those are all different types of gray so he prefers high contrast solutions in black and white.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Welcome! One can define `pics` for these symbols. What makes this delicate/interesting is that the color and placement of the components depend on whether or not other components are present. This proposal takes care of this by first starting a survey and then draw the components. That way if you say

```
\pic{ADD={red,white,blue}};
```

you will get

[image]

whereas if you add `yellow`,

```
\pic{ADD={red,white,blue,yellow}};
```

you get

[image]

and if you replace `white` by `black`

[image]

This is the full code with these and more examples:

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds}
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305/194703
\tikzset{scale line widths/.style={%
/utils/exec=\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\myJacobian*0.4pt}%
\def\tikz@semiaddlinewidth##1{\pgfmathsetmacro{\my@lw}{\myJacobian*##1}%
\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{\my@lw pt}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\my@lw pt}},%
thin}}
\makeatother
\newif\ifADDcontainsyellow
\newif\ifADDcontainsblack
\tikzset{pics/ADD/.style={code={
\tikzset{ADD survey/.cd,#1}
\tikzset{ADD/.cd,#1}
}},
/tikz/ADD survey/.cd,
white/.code={},blue/.code={},red/.code={},
yellow/.code={\ADDcontainsyellowtrue},black/.code={\ADDcontainsblacktrue},
/tikz/ADD/.cd,
white/.code={\draw[rounded corners=3pt,scale line widths,line width=0.6mm]
(-0.47,-0.47) rectangle (0.47,0.47);},
black/.code={\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[black] [rounded corners=3pt] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{scope}},
red/.code={\fill[rounded corners=1.8pt] \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi
(-0.3,-0.25) \ifADDcontainsyellow ++(120:0.1) \fi
 |- ++ (0.5,0.5) --
cycle;},
blue/.code={\fill[rounded corners=1.8pt]  \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi
(-0.2,-0.25) \ifADDcontainsyellow ++(-60:0.1) \fi -| ++ (0.5,0.5) --
cycle;},
yellow/.code={\draw[line cap=round,scale line widths,line width=0.7mm]
 \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi (-0.35,-0.35) -- (0.35,0.35);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
 \path pic{ADD={red,white,blue}}
 (1.5,0) pic{ADD={red,white,blue,yellow}}
 (3,0) pic{ADD={red,black,blue}}
 (4.5,0) pic{ADD={blue,yellow,red,black}}
 (6,0) pic{ADD={red,blue}};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

As you can see, by saying

```
\path (<x>,<y>) pic{ADD=...};
```

you move the symbol to the coordinates. Some part of the preamble is only to ensure scalability.

The Venn diagram from [your link](http://www.coloradd.net/code.asp) can be obtained e.g. using [this unofficial library](https://github.com/tallmarmot/pgf/tree/master/experiments/Marmot/Venn).

```
\documentclass[tikz,border=3mm]{standalone}
\usetikzlibrary{backgrounds,venn}
\makeatletter% https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305/194703
\tikzset{scale line widths/.style={%
/utils/exec=\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myJacobian}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}%
\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\myJacobian*0.4pt}%
\def\tikz@semiaddlinewidth##1{\pgfmathsetmacro{\my@lw}{\myJacobian*##1}%
\tikz@addoption{\pgfsetlinewidth{\my@lw pt}}\pgfmathsetlength\pgflinewidth{\my@lw pt}},%
thin}}
\makeatother
\newif\ifADDcontainsyellow
\newif\ifADDcontainsblack
\tikzset{pics/ADD/.style={code={
\tikzset{ADD survey/.cd,#1}
\tikzset{ADD/.cd,#1}
}},
/tikz/ADD survey/.cd,
white/.code={},blue/.code={},red/.code={},
yellow/.code={\ADDcontainsyellowtrue},black/.code={\ADDcontainsblacktrue},
/tikz/ADD/.cd,
white/.code={\draw[rounded corners=3pt,scale line widths,line width=0.6mm]
(-0.47,-0.47) rectangle (0.47,0.47);},
black/.code={\begin{scope}[on background layer]
    \fill[black] [rounded corners=3pt] (-0.5,-0.5) rectangle (0.5,0.5);
\end{scope}},
red/.code={\fill[rounded corners=1.8pt] \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi
(-0.3,-0.25) \ifADDcontainsyellow ++(120:0.1) \fi
 |- ++ (0.5,0.5) --
cycle;},
blue/.code={\fill[rounded corners=1.8pt]  \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi
(-0.2,-0.25) \ifADDcontainsyellow ++(-60:0.1) \fi -| ++ (0.5,0.5) --
cycle;},
yellow/.code={\draw[line cap=round,scale line widths,line width=0.7mm]
 \ifADDcontainsblack [white]\fi (-0.35,-0.35) -- (0.35,0.35);}}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}[Venn diagram={offset angle=60,
 all labels/.style={opacity=0},
 radius=1.4cm,distance=1cm}]
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=A];
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=B];
  \fill[red,venn/set=C];
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=C];
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=A];
  \fill[blue,venn/set=B];
 \end{scope}
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=B];
  \clip[current reverse clip,venn/set=C];
  \fill[yellow,venn/set=A];
 \end{scope}
 \path[fill=green,venn/and={A and B}];
 \path[fill=orange,venn/and={A and C}];
 \path[fill=purple,venn/and={B and C}];
 \begin{scope}
  \clip[venn/set=A];
  \clip[venn/set=B];
  \fill[venn/set=C];
 \end{scope}
 \path[scale=0.7,transform shape] (-150:2) pic{ADD={yellow}}
  (-30:2) pic{ADD={blue}} (90:2) pic{ADD={red}}
  (-90:1.3) pic{ADD={yellow,blue}}
  (150:1.3) pic{ADD={yellow,red}}
  (30:1.3) pic{ADD={blue,red}} ;
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: As always, great work! Can I suggest you to replace the value 2.7pt for the rounded corner of the rectangle `(-0.45,-0.45) rectangle (0.45,0.45)` in `white/.code` (in the first code) by a smaller value? I find that a value of 1.58pt gives a better look for the inner rounded corner of the border (so the border is not inflated in corners). The value 1.58pt comes from 3 pt minus 1.42 pt (the width of the border is 0.5 cm - 0.45 cm = 0.05 cm = 1.42 pt)

Comment: @quark67 Thanks! I agree with your point, but solved it slightly differently by just drawing  line with some rounded corners and scaling line widths.

Comment: Wow this sure helps a lot! Thanks for all the work you put in there. I thought there might be some symbol package out there that I didn't know or something similar to patterns. I didn't expect someone to actually build the whole thing complete with a shortcut! You are awesome!