# Tikz option scale= only scaling vertical, not horizontal

Tags: tikz-pgf, scaling

I am using `scale=` option to scale a `tikzpicture` and wondeing what is the best way to propely handle the scaling of the red horizontal line in such a case.

[image]

### Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}

\newcommand*{\MyTikzPicture}{%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=\Scale]
        \def\@HalfLineWidth{20pt}%
        \draw [line width=2*\@HalfLineWidth, line cap=round] (2.0,3.0) -- (2.0,6.0)
            node [below, pos=0] {scale=\Scale};
        
        \begin{scope}[xshift=-\@HalfLineWidth]
            \draw [line width=2.0pt, red] (2.0,3.0) -- ++(2*\@HalfLineWidth,0);
        \end{scope}
    \end{tikzpicture}%
}%

\begin{document}

\def\Scale{1.0}
\MyTikzPicture
\quad
\def\Scale{2.0}
\MyTikzPicture

\end{document}
```

Comment: May I lure you [here](https://topanswers.xyz/tex?q=819#a965)? Otherwise you may be interested in [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/515305), which has a `scale line width` key that can be used here to scale the line width of the red line.

Comment: @Schrödinger'scat: Your second asnwer works great. Thanks.