# Get value of global scale in in TikZ-picture

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfkeys, pgfmath, scale

I calculate some lengths of a path (without the use of the `let` operator!).
To achieve that I use the `\pgfgetlastxy{}{};` command (which works fine so far) but if I scale the picture, the calculations do not make sense anymore, as I cannot take the scaling factor into account.

The following code should demonstrate my problem.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\tikzset{dot/.style={circle, fill, inner sep=2pt}}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1]
        \draw (0,0) node[below] {scale = 1} -- (20pt,60pt);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\myLastX}{\myLastY};
        \node[dot, label={right:(\myLastX, \myLastY)}] at (\myLastX, \myLastY) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw (0,0) node[below] {scale = 0.5} -- (20pt,60pt);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\myLastX}{\myLastY}; 
        \node[dot, label={right:(\myLastX, \myLastY)}] at (\myLastX, \myLastY) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
        \draw (0,0) node[below] {scale = 0.5 (what I want)} -- (20pt,60pt);
        \pgfgetlastxy{\myLastX}{\myLastY}; 
        % \getglobalscale{\globalscale} <--- How to get the global value?
        \pgfmathsetmacro\globalscale{0.5}
        \node[dot, label={right:(\myLastX, \myLastY)}] at (\myLastX/\globalscale, \myLastY/\globalscale) {};
    \end{tikzpicture}
%
    % Does not work
    % \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=0.5]
    %     \draw (0,0) node[below] {scale = 0.5 (what I want)} -- (20pt,60pt);
    %     \pgfgetlastxy{\myLastX}{\myLastY}; 
    %     \pgfkeysgetvalue{/tikz/scale}{\globalscale}
    %     \node[dot, label={right:(\myLastX, \myLastY)}] at (\myLastX/\globalscale, \myLastY/\globalscale) {};
    % \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**TL;DR:** To solve my (initial) problem I need to get the value of the global picture scale. The way I tried to get it in the last code snippet did not work. Is there any other way to get it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best answer about this is [@Circumscribe very nice post](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474035/38080); you can also look at the solution [proposed by @marmot](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/506249/38080) (a user that unfortunately is not here anymore).

Summarizing, this code:

```latex
\pgfgettransformentries{\tmpa}{\tmpb}{\tmpc}{\tmpd}{\tmp}{\tmp}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{\myscale}{sqrt(abs(\tmpa*\tmpd-\tmpb*\tmpc))}%
```

should give you the global scale (even when there are rotations or different `x-` and `y-` scale).

The Ti*k*Z manual says:
[image]

Comment: The first user who used this is @Circumscribe here: [Recover scaling factor in TikZ](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/474035/138900)

Comment: @AndréC thanks, edited-