Tikz Display Coordinate in Node Text in Scaled Picture
Looking to display the value of a coordinate, however using the below, the value does not print out accurately.
The scale is attempted to be retreived using Recover scaling factor in TikZ and then use the scale factor value like in Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ. However, the @scalefactor returns 1 always in \xcoord and \ycoord despite showing the actual factor if used in the Tikz picture.
Any ideas on how to fix?
%!TeX program = lualatex
\documentclass[12pt]{article}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{math, calc}

%% https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/86897/recover-scaling-factor-in-tikz
\newcommand*\getscale[1]{%
\begingroup
\pgfgettransformentries{\scaleA}{\scaleB}{\scaleC}{\scaleD}{\whatevs}{\whatevs}%
\pgfmathsetmacro{#1}{sqrt(abs(\scaleA*\scaleD-\scaleB*\scaleC))}%
\expandafter
\endgroup
\expandafter\def\expandafter#1\expandafter{#1}%
}

% for printing out coordinates in Tikz coordinate variable
\makeatletter
\newcommand\xcoord[1]{{%
    \getscale{\@scalefactor}%
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}%
    \pgfmathparse{\pgf@x/\pgf@xx/\@scalefactor}%
    \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%    
}}
\newcommand\ycoord[1]{{%
        \getscale{\@scalefactor}%
        \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}%
        \pgfmathparse{\pgf@y/\pgf@yy/\@scalefactor}%
        \pgfmathprintnumber{\pgfmathresult}%
}}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{figure}
    \centering
    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=1/10]
        % GRID - X
        \foreach \i in {0,24,...,120}{
            \draw[gray, thin] (\i,-12) -- (\i,184);
            \tikzmath{int \value; \value = \i;}; 
            \node[gray, below] at (\i,-12) {\value};
        }
        
        % GRID - Y
        \foreach \i in {0,24,...,168}{
            \draw[gray, thin] (-12,\i) -- (132,\i);
            \tikzmath{int \value; \value = \i;};
            \node[gray, left] at (-12,\i) {\value};
        }
    
        % Draw some lines with relative coordinates
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++(12,0) coordinate (c);
        \draw[thick] (0,0) -- ++(0,60) coordinate (c);
        \draw[thick] (c) -- ++(0,36) coordinate (c);
        \draw[thick] (c) -- ++(0,76) coordinate (c);
        \draw[thick] (c) -- ++(120,0) coordinate (c);
        
        % Display coordinate
        \getscale{\scalefactor};
        \node[fill=white, text=blue] at (60,60) {Scale = \scalefactor};
        \node[fill=white, text=magenta, yshift=-15pt] at (c) {(\xcoord{c}, \ycoord{c})};            
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{figure}
\end{document}

The above compiles, however the coordinate in magenta does not match where the black line ends which is (120, 172).


Can you add an image that shows the result you get? Compiling your code I don't see any problems.

What‘s your motivation? Curiosity? Thank you

@AndréC Picture added. Please note the magenta coordinate is incorrect.

@MS-SPO Looking to be able to get the coordinate after drawing something with relative coordinates to be able to relate to physical space.

The way to obtain the original, not transformed coordinate can be found here Accessing the logic values of a TikZ coordinate.
Using the custom command
\makeatletter
\def\extractcoord#1#2#3{
  \path let \p1=(#3) in \pgfextra{
    \pgfmathsetmacro#1{\x{1}/\pgf@xx}
    \pgfmathsetmacro#2{\y{1}/\pgf@yy}
    \xdef#1{#1} \xdef#2{#2}
  };
}
\makeatother

one can display a coordinate like so
\coordinate (A) at (120,172);
\extractcoord{\x}{\y}{A};
\node at (A) {Coordinates: \x, \y};

This was tested with scaling, unit changes in both x and y, and scope environments.

This is an issue of manually labeling the tics: you are "computing" the x-labels by \tikzmath{int \value; \value = \i;}; but this does not know anything about the scaling because these are just numbers and no "tikz coordinates".
The solution is to manually do the scaling, e.g., by
\tikzmath{int \value; \value = \i * \scalefactor;}; 

You might have to consider that using \value as an integer gives some rounding errors, but that's an other issue.

That would adjust the grid coordinates. The intent is to get the original, unscaled grid coordinates.
