# Compute the elevation of a coordinate in TikZ

Tags: tikz-pgf, pgfmath

I'm wracking my brains over a seemingly simple problem. Given a coordinate, I would like to do some computation with its components. More specifically, I want to compute the elevation of a point.

Consider this M(not)WE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \coordinate (A) at (2,3);

    \newdimen\x
    \newdimen\y
    \pgfextractx{\x}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
    \pgfextracty{\y}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
    \pgfmathparse{atan2(\y,\x)}
    \node at (1,1) {\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

My goal is to extract the x and the y component from the point A, compute the elevation, and print this in a node. How can I achieve this?

Comment: Related Questions: [Extract x, y coordinate of an arbitrary point in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/33703/extract-x-y-coordinate-of-an-arbitrary-point-in-tikz) and [Extract x value from coordinate in TikZ](http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66125/extract-x-value-from-coordinate-in-tikz/).

Comment: Remark: the extraction part is correct (same as in the question linked above), but the bug in this **specific question** is that `\pgfmathresult` value is overridden by the implementation of `\node`. Using `\pgfmathsetmacro` or computing the `\pgfmathresult` "late" as in the answer below does not suffer from this issue.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

You can use

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
%
  \newdimen\x
  \newdimen\y
  \pgfextractx{\x}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
  \pgfextracty{\y}{\pgfpointanchor{A}{center}}
  \node at (1,1) {\pgfmathparse{atan2(\y,\x)}\pgfmathresult};
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

or

```
\def\myresult{\pgfmathparse{atan2(\y,\x)}\pgfmathresult}
\node at (1,1) {\myresult};
```

or

```
\pgfmathsetmacro\myresult{atan2(\y,\x)}
\node at (1,1) {\myresult};
```

Comment: Thanks! One question though. Say I want to use `\myresult` as a coordinate in a polar coordinate, as in `\node at (\myresult:1) {test};`, how can I do that?

Comment: Nevermind, with `\pgfmathsetmacro` it works.

Answer (score 2):

There is a standard way to do it using `let` like this :

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (2,3);
  \path let \p1=(A) in node{\x1};
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

And if you want it as a number (or in cm) you can see [this answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/15002/9335).