# Comparing node coordinates in Tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf, etoolbox

I am trying to generate drawings automatically based on node coordinates. The construction process itself is very easy: draw an arrow from node i to node i+1 (i and i+1 being node **names**, fixed beforehand, and which I do not want to modify). The tricky part is that nodes can be laid out in any order on a line, and I would like all arcs to be drawn above the horizontal line. I have attempted in vain to extract the `x` coordinates of my nodes and to compare them using `\ifnumcomp`:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}

This is fine:
\begin{tikzpicture}
% node placement
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (0) at (0, 0) [label=below:0] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (1) at (1, 0) [label=below:1] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (2) at (2, 0) [label=below:2] {};
\foreach [count=\q from 0] \p in {1, 2}
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend left=60] (\p);
% arcs
\end{tikzpicture}

This is not fine:
\begin{tikzpicture}
% node placement
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (0) at (0, 0) [label=below:0] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (2) at (1, 0) [label=below:2] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (1) at (2, 0) [label=below:1] {};
\foreach [count=\q from 0] \p in {1, 2}
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend left=60] (\p);
% arcs
\end{tikzpicture}, I want it to look like this: \begin{tikzpicture}
% node placement
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (0) at (0, 0) [label=below:0] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (2) at (1, 0) [label=below:2] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (1) at (2, 0) [label=below:1] {};
% \foreach [count=\q from 0] \p in {1, 2}
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (0) to [bend left=60] (1);
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (1) to [bend right=60] (2);
% arcs
\end{tikzpicture}

This attempt at combining \verb|\ifnumcomp| and \verb|\pgfextractx| fails:
\begin{tikzpicture}
% node placement
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (0) at (0, 0) [label=below:0] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (2) at (1, 0) [label=below:2] {};
\node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (1) at (2, 0) [label=below:1] {};
\foreach [count=\q from 0] \p in {1, 2} {
    \newdimen\px
    \newdimen\qx
    \pgfextractx{\px}{\p}
    \pgfextractx{\qx}{\q}
    \ifnumcomp{\qx}{<}{\px}{
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend left=60] (\p);
    }{
    \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend right=60] (\p);
    }
}
% arcs
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```

The document renders as follows:

[image]

How can I fix my attempted solution? (or does anyone know a "better" / "simpler" / ... solution?)

(For better looking drawings, bend angles should probably be proportional to the distance between nodes, but I suppose this should be a separate question).

Comment: For coordinates extraction, [I would recommend to try this solution.](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66129/204164)

Comment: @SebGlav: thanks, this seems to do the trick. I must misunderstand how `\pgfextractx` works, but plugging in Andrew Stacey's command works perfectly.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Using [Andrew Stacey's answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/33765/440) to [a related question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/33703/440) allows me to obtain the wanted result. Here's a complete working example:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{etoolbox}
\usepackage{tikz}
% Andrew Stacey's code:
\makeatletter
\newcommand{\gettikzxy}[3]{%
\tikz@scan@one@point\pgfutil@firstofone#1\relax
\edef#2{\the\pgf@x}%
\edef#3{\the\pgf@y}%
}
\makeatother

\begin{document}

\begin{tikzpicture}
    % node placement
    \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (0) at (0, 0) [label=below:0] {};
    \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (2) at (1, 0) [label=below:2] {};
    \node[circle,draw,inner sep=2pt] (1) at (2, 0) [label=below:1] {};

    % arcs
    \foreach [count=\q from 0] \p in {1, 2} {
        \gettikzxy{(\p)}{\px}{\py}
        \gettikzxy{(\q)}{\qx}{\qy}
        \ifdimcomp{\qx}{<}{\px}{
            \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend left=60] (\p);
        }{
            \draw[->,>=stealth] (\q) to [bend right=60] (\p);
        }
    }
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}
```