Using macro \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord} to get x and y component for axis cs
In my MNWE see below, I can't imagine what I am doing wrong. Also see the attached picture. I try to extract coordinate with slightly modified macro given in the answer for  tex.stackexchange.com/questions/78761.
When I simply add the circle with \fill command:
  \fill[blue] (\XCoord, \YCoord) circle (2pt) node[right, blue] {\(A[2,6]\)};

everything works well. But strangely when I reset some of the x, y components suddenly the point lies on the wrong coordinates as the picture shows. I have absolutely no idea how the variables \XCoord and \YCoord are modified.
The \ExtractCoordinate is modified with
  \pgfplotsextra{
  \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}

to obtain x,y coordinates relative to axis cs. I'm not sure that's right.

My motivation:
MNWE is a snipped version of the drawing in which I originally wanted to draw dashed lines that would plot the position of a point on the axes. I wanted to draw these dashed lines this way:
\draw[dashed] (A) node[left, green] 
  {\(A[2,6]\)} -- (\XCoord,0) (A) -- (0,\YCoord);

MNWE:
\documentclass[11pt]{standalone}
\usepackage[usenames,x11names]{xcolor}
\usepackage{pgfplots}
  \pgfplotsset{compat=newest}
  \usepgfplotslibrary{fillbetween}
  \usetikzlibrary{calc, intersections}
  \usetikzlibrary{decorations.markings}
  \usetikzlibrary{patterns}
  \usetikzlibrary{arrows.meta}
\usepackage{amsmath}

  % ~~~~~~~~~~~ XY Coordinate ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~
% http://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/66125/extract-x-value-from-coordinate-in-tikz
\newdimen\XCoord
\newdimen\YCoord
\newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{
  \pgfplotsextra{
    \pgfpointanchor{#1}{center}
    \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord}
    % Convert back to axis cs
    % \pgfmathsetmacro{\XCoord}{\XCoord/\pgfplotsunitxlength}
    % \pgfmathsetmacro{\YCoord}{\YCoord/\pgfplotsunitylength}
  }
}
% \newcommand*{\ExtractCoordinate}[1]{\path (#1); \pgfgetlastxy{\XCoord}{\YCoord};}%

\begin{document}

\def \globalscale {1}

\begin{tikzpicture}[
  thick, scale=\globalscale,
]

  \begin{axis}[
    domain=-2:3,
    xmin = -4, xmax = 6, 
    ymin = -4, ymax = 8,
    x=15pt, y=15pt,
    grid style={line width=.2pt, draw=gray!20},
    major grid style={solid, line width=.4pt, draw=gray!60},
    minor grid style={solid, line width=.2pt, draw=gray!30},
    minor tick num=5,
    grid = both,   % both, major
    clip = true,
    clip mode =individual,
    axis x line = middle, 
    axis y line = middle,
    xlabel={\(x\)},
    ylabel={\(y\)}
  ]


  \coordinate (A) at (2,6);
  
  % point A:  
  \ExtractCoordinate{A};
  \fill[blue] (\XCoord, \YCoord) circle (2pt) node[right, blue] {\(A[2,6]\)};

  \fill[blue] (\XCoord,0) circle (2pt);
  \fill[blue] (0,\YCoord) circle (2pt);

  \end{axis} 
\end{tikzpicture}

\end{document}


Inside the axis environment you have much better access via its coordinate systems. Just do \fill[blue] (A|-0,0) circle[radius=2pt]; \fill[blue] (A-|0,0) circle[radius=2pt];.

Basically, the same problem why your points show up differently: Q685701

Also the correct point will be obtained if I use (\XCoord, 0pt) instead of (\XCoord, 0). I didn't realize that trap either.
