# How to label sets in Venn diagram using venndiagram package

Tags: labels

How do I have the labels (A and B) outside the circles? I would like a solution that uses the `venndiagram` package.

Code:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=blue,tikzoptions={opacity=0.5}]
        \fillOnlyA
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

**Solution 1.:**

(Modified after the comment of @CarLaTeX)

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\begin{document}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=blue,tikzoptions={opacity=0.5},labelA={},labelB={}]
        \fillOnlyA
\setpostvennhook
        {
            \draw (labelA) node[above=2pt] {A};
            \draw (labelB) node[above=2pt] {B};
            }
    \end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

**Solution 2.:**

You could use `tikzlibrary` `calc`, and with its help, it's easy to put the labels on certain coordinates.

(I used @Jake's answer for [TikZ: Node at same x-coordinate as another node, but specified y-coordinate?](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate))

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
    \begin{venndiagram2sets}[shade=blue,tikzoptions={opacity=0.5},labelA={},labelB={}]
        \fillOnlyA
\setpostvennhook
        {
            \path let \p1 = (labelA) in node at (\x1,3.2) {A};
            \path let \p2 = (labelB) in node at (\x2,0.2) {B};
            }
   \end{venndiagram2sets}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks for both solutions. This is just what I was looking for!

Comment: In solution 1 you could put `above=2pt` to shift the node a bit up, without using`calc`.

Comment: You do not need `calc` for the second scenario: `\path node at (labelA|-0,3.2) {A};
            \path node at (labelB|-0,0.2) {B};`