# Universal set in Venn diagrams

Tags: tikz-pgf, venn-diagrams

I have not used the `venndiagram` package before. I have tried to read the manual, but could not find an answer to how to make the universal set box fit for any number of elements.

Here is what I have so far:

```
    \documentclass{book}

 \usepackage{newfile}
 \usepackage{amsmath}
 \usepackage{xifthen}
 \usepackage{enumitem}
 \usepackage{multicol}
 \usepackage{lipsum}
 \usepackage{multirow}
 \usepackage{blindtext}
 \usepackage{amsfonts}
 \usepackage{booktabs}
 \usepackage{longtable}
 \usepackage{makecell}
 \usepackage{cancel}
 \usepackage{tikz}
 \usetikzlibrary{tikzmark,shapes.misc}
 \usepackage{venndiagram}
 \usetikzlibrary{fit}
 \usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}
\usepackage{cellspace}
%------------------------------------


%-----------------------------------

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}




\usepackage{verbatim}
%\usepackage[active,tightpage]{preview}
%\PreviewEnvironment{tikzpicture}
%\setlength\PreviewBorder{5pt}%

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

 \tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
    outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

 \setlength{\parskip}{5mm}


\begin{document}

 \chapter{Sets and Venn Diagrams}

     \section{Sets}

  A set is a specific group of numbers or items from a list.          The items in this set   (the list list), are called Elements.\\
Sets can be written in a few different ways - eg the set $A$      can be  written as,  $A=\{1,8,27,64\}$, $A=\{Cube \: numbers    <100\}$ and  $A=\{x:x \:is \:a \:cube \:number   \:less \:than    \:100\}$

     \section{Set Notiation}

 If we take the natural numbers, $\mathbb{N} \leq10$ 

  \begin{tabular}{|c|c|c|c|}
  \hline
   Sybmol             & Name                       & Example                                                                  & Explanation\\
  \hline
 $\{\}$                  & Set                           &   \thead{$A=\{1,3\}$ \\ $B=\{2,3,9\}$ \\ $C=\{3,9\}$} &  Collection   of objects or items\\
 \hline
 $\cap$                & intersect                   & $A \cap    B = \{3\}$                                                  &  3    belongs to both sets $A$ and $B$ \\
 \hline
 $\cup$                & Union                        & $A \cup    B = \{1,2,3,9\}$                                         & The       elements belong to both $A$ and $B$ \\
 \hline
 $\xi$                    & The universal set     & $\xi=\ {4,5,6,7,8,10\}$                                             & All     the elements not in the sets  \\
 \hline
 $\subset$            & Proper subset          & \thead{$\{1\}    \cup A$  \\ $C \cup B$}                     & A set is contained in    another set \\
 \hline
 $\subseteq$        &Subest                      & $\thead{B   \subseteq A \\ \{1,3\}}$                          &  A set that is     contained in or equal to another set\\
 \hline
 $\not \subseteq$ & Not a proper subset & $\{1,3\}$                                                                  & A set the is not contained in another set \\
 \hline
 $\supset$            & Superset                  & $B  \supset C$                                                     &  Set $B$   includes set $C$\\
 \hline
 $\epsilon$           & is a member of         & $3 \epsilon  A$                                                     & $3$ is in  the set $A$\\
 \hline
 $\not\epsilon$     & is not a member of   & $4 \not\epsilon A $                                                  & $4$ is not in   the set $A $\\
 \hline

 \end{tabular}


  %--------------------------Problem code is here------------------%

 my attempt
 \begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={1},labelOnlyB=  {2},labelOnlyC={}, labelOnlyAB={},labelOnlyAC={},labelOnlyBC=  {9},labelABC={3}, labelNotABC={4,5,6,7,8,10}]
     \end{venndiagram3sets} %My Attempt

 %------------------------------------%

 First suggestion
 \begin{venndiagram3sets}[
   labelOnlyA={1},
   labelOnlyB={2},
   labelOnlyC={},
   labelOnlyAB= {},
   labelOnlyAC={},
   labelOnlyBC={9},
   labelABC={3},
   labelNotABC={4,5,6,7,8,10},
    showframe=false,
 ]
  \setpostvennhook{
   \node[below left] at (venn top right) {\(\mathcal{E}\)};
   \node[fit=(venn top right) (venn bottom left)   (labelNotABC),draw] {};
 }
 \end{venndiagram3sets} % second attempt

  %--------------------------------------------%
  Second suggestion
  \fbox{\begin{venndiagram3sets}[showframe=false,labelOnlyA= {1},labelOnlyB={2},labelOnlyC={}, labelOnlyAB= {},labelOnlyAC= {},labelOnlyBC={9},labelABC={3}, labelNotABC={$\xi$ \ {4,5,6,7,8,10\}}]
     \end{venndiagram3sets}} %third attempt

  %-----------And ends here----------------------------------%

  %Diagrams

     \section{diagrams}

     % Definition of circles

  \begin{tabular}{cc}
  % Set A and B
 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}
          \clip \firstcircle;
          \fill[filled] \secondcircle;
     \end{scope}
     \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$A$};
     \draw[outline] \secondcircle node {$B$};
     \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cap B$};
 \end{tikzpicture}

 &
  %Set A or B but not (A and B) also known a A xor B
  \begin{tikzpicture}
     \draw[filled, even odd rule] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                                  \secondcircle node{$B$};
     \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north)  {$\overline{A \cap B}$};
  \end{tikzpicture}

  % Set A or B
 \begin{tikzpicture}
      \draw[filled] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                   \secondcircle node {$B$};
      \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A \cup B$};
 \end{tikzpicture}\\

 % Set A but not B
 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}
         \clip \firstcircle;
         \draw[filled, even odd rule] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                                      \secondcircle;
     \end{scope}
     \draw[outline] \firstcircle
                    \secondcircle node {$B$};
     \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$A - B$};
     \end{tikzpicture}

 &
 % Set B but not A
 \begin{tikzpicture}
     \begin{scope}
         \clip \secondcircle;
         \draw[filled, even odd rule] \firstcircle
                                      \secondcircle node {$B$};
     \end{scope}
     \draw[outline] \firstcircle node {$A$}
                    \secondcircle;
     \node[anchor=south] at (current bounding box.north) {$B -  A$};
 \end{tikzpicture}\\

 \end{tabular}

 \end{document}
```

I have edited this to provide all the code for my page incase anything is causing my problems. sorry for the long code.[image]

Comment: Just to clarify: do you want the square to be larger so that `$\xi$ \{4,5,6,7,8,10\}` is inside the square?

Comment: Yes, but automatically resize depending on the number of elements, if that is possible.

Comment: You should maybe tidy the code of your MWE. You load `tikz` twice and it is unclear to me why you define some circles which you don't use later.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I am not sure what you want to achieve, but I think you want to place the label for the universal set at a place where it does not intersect with the surrounding box.

[This answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/410196/47927) explains how you can use the macro `\setpostvennhook` to customize the position of the labels. The manual of the package further adds that there are coordinates in all four corners of the venn diagram, which you can use to align the labels. You can also use the options `vgap` or `hgap` to increase the margin between the circles and the outer box.

Of course, if the contents of the label is too long, it will eventually "crash" into the right border of the surrounding box ...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\begin{document}

\begin{venndiagram3sets}[labelOnlyA={1}, labelOnlyB={2}, labelOnlyC={}, labelOnlyAB= {}, labelOnlyAC={}, labelOnlyBC={9}, labelABC={3}, vgap=.75cm]

    \setpostvennhook{
        \node[anchor=south west] at (venn bottom left) {$\xi$ \{4,5,6,7,8,10\}};
    }

\end{venndiagram3sets}

\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 4):

You can use the `\setpostvennhook` to insert arbitrary TikZ code to be drawn after the venn diagram is constructed.  Since the default size of the frame doesn't take into account the labels, it can be redrawn here taking that into account.  Specifically, using the `fit` library then a node can be drawn that is guaranteed to encompass the diagram and the non-ABC label.  Note that you need the option `showframe=false` to avoid drawing the original universal set frame.

I've also make a couple of other changes:

1. The elements not in the sets A,B,C shouldn't be enclosed in braces.  Technically, writing `\{4,5,6,7,8,10\}` indicates that the outer region contains **one** element which is the **set** containing 4,5,6,7,8,10.  I presume that what you want to indicate is that the outer region *itself* contains those numbers.
2. To avoid the symbol for the universal set getting confused with the elements, I've used the `\setpostvennhook` to place its symbol in the top right corner (which, I think, is a more standard place for it to be).  I've also used `\mathcal{E}` rather than `\xi`.

```
\documentclass{book}
%\url{https://tex.stackexchange.com/q/653355/86}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{venndiagram}
\usetikzlibrary{fit}


\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\begin{document}
\begin{venndiagram3sets}[
  labelOnlyA={1},
  labelOnlyB={2},
  labelOnlyC={},
  labelOnlyAB= {},
  labelOnlyAC={},
  labelOnlyBC={9},
  labelABC={3},
  labelNotABC={4,5,6,7,8,10},
  showframe=false,
]
\setpostvennhook{
  \node[below left] at (venn top right) {\(\mathcal{E}\)};
  \node[fit=(venn top right) (venn bottom left) (labelNotABC),draw] {};
}
\end{venndiagram3sets}
\end{document}
```

[image: Venn diagram with universal set adjusted to fit contents]

Answer (score 3):

Instead of letting the `venndiagram` package draw the rectangle, you could wrap it into an `\fbox`

```
\documentclass{book}

\usepackage{makecell}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{venndiagram}

\renewcommand\theadfont{\bfseries}

\usepackage{cellspace}

\usepackage{tikz}
\usepackage{verbatim}

\usepackage[left=2.00cm, right=1.00cm, top=3.00cm, bottom=3.00cm]{geometry}

\def\firstcircle{(0,0) circle (1.5cm)}
\def\secondcircle{(0:2cm) circle (1.5cm)}

\colorlet{circle edge}{blue!50}
\colorlet{circle area}{blue!20}

\tikzset{filled/.style={fill=circle area, draw=circle edge, thick},
     outline/.style={draw=circle edge, thick}}

\setlength{\parskip}{5mm}


\begin{document}
\fbox{\begin{venndiagram3sets}[showframe=false,labelOnlyA={1},labelOnlyB={2},labelOnlyC={}, labelOnlyAB= {},labelOnlyAC={},labelOnlyBC={9},labelABC={3}, labelNotABC={$\xi$ \{4,5,6,7,8,10\}}]
    \end{venndiagram3sets}}
    \end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Thanks @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz but when I run this cadet does give me the right sized box but also gives me the original box, am I running it on LaTex should I be using something different I have tried ExLaTex and other but nothing seems to work.

Comment: @PaulA Did you add the `showframe=false` to switch off the original box?

Comment: Hi @samcarter_is_at_topanswers.xyz
 I turned show frame to false, in fact I have tried to just copy and paste your code and it still will not work. I think I need to go back to basics as everything I have read suggested the same as you.

Comment: @PaulA Maybe version of the `venndiagram` package is too old? I think the option was added sometime in 2017 or 2018.

Comment: I have voted to close this question so I can reopen it with all the details of the full page. not sure if this is the proper way to do things, but it's all I can think to do.

Comment: @PaulA Why do you want to close it? You can edit it if your additional information does not invalidate existing answers. Closing is definitely not appropriate.

Comment: I have edited the code to show the whole worksheet I didn't do it before as its messy and needs sorting out, but not by anyone here, I have added a picture of my rendering.

Comment: @PaulA There are two incorrect spaces in your code.  With the spaces fixed  https://pastebin.com/RgPuEBFJ I get this output https://i.stack.imgur.com/5d9vA.png . As said before, I suspect you have an old version of the `venndiagram` package.

Comment: I would need to see your .log file to check the version

Comment: https://pastebin.com/z1dkWudM If it is a old version can you point me to how i would do that as my text shop says everything is up to date.

Comment: @PaulA You are using texlive 2017, the current version is texlive 2022, you can get the new version by installing it from https://tug.org/texlive/ . Texshop is just an editor, the version of texshop is not important.

Comment: Thank You so much this solved my problem completely, I just didn't realise I had to download newer versions and not just relay on updates, I will keep this in mind from now on.

Comment: @PaulA You're welcome! Have fun with all the very important new packages in texlive 2022 like https://www.ctan.org/pkg/sillypage :)  (during the year, one can simply update texlive to get all the new package versions, but once a year one needs to install the new version)