# Mixing relative and absolute coordinates in tikz

Tags: tikz-pgf

The following example uses `circuitikz`, but the question is about expressing coordinates in generic `tikz`.

Look at the following code:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) node[npn](Q1){};
        \draw (Q1.E) to[R=$R_E$] (0,-2.5) node[ground]{};
        \draw [gray] (Q1.E) -- ++(2,0) 
            coordinate(tmp) to[C, color=gray] (tmp |- 0, -2.5) 
            node[ground, color=gray]{};
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

where all the grounds are supposed to be at *(x, -2.5)*. The tricky thing is the coordinate `(tmp |- 0, -2.5)` (hint from [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18406/38080)): what I want to express is the concept of a coordinate which is

> (the current path *x*, the absolute *y* -2.5)

and the solution I found is, as you can see, using a temporary node. Is there an easier way to write that coordinate?

BTW, for easier way I mean something to directly say "move to the coordinate that has the current value of x, and y=-2.5", like for example

```
\draw [gray] (Q1.E) -- ++(2,0) 
            to[C, color=gray] (\magiccurrentx, -2.5) 
            node[ground, color=gray]{};
```

...or a similar thing.

[image: output of the snippet above]

Comment: @phelype-oleinik, thanks for the edit.

Comment: if you know distance from `(Q1.E)` to `(0,-2.5)` than you can use only relative coordinates: `\draw [gray] (Q1.E) -- ++(2,0) to[C, color=gray] ++ (0,-1.73)
            node[ground, color=gray]{};`.  as i see your mwe, this distance is not known, so you determine end of this path by coordinate defined by `(tmp |- 0, -2.5) `. as far as i know, for this is no better way.

Comment: I am sorry, I do not understand the question. Isn't `(tmp |- 0, -2.5)` already what you're looking for? If not, please consider editing `(the current path x, the absolute y -2.5)` in such a way that it is a bit clearer.

Comment: @marmot sorry --- for simpler I mean not having to use a temporary node; some magic to say "move to a coordinate that has the current value of x, and y=-2.5". I have made myself clearer in the question (I hope).

Comment: If anyone reads this question because of the title, refer to [TikZ: Scale image but maintain absolute distance - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/570822/tikz-scale-image-but-maintain-absolute-distance) .

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to save code characters you simply change `coordinate(coordinate_name)` for `node(node_name){}` and use one `\draw` statement, relative coordinates, and you can use the node ground coordinate named as `G` to find the coordinate intersection of the named coordinates from the short of the capacitor and the ground; to change the color including the nodes use `color=your_fav_color`, in my case red.

RESULT:

[image]

MWE:

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[american]
        \draw
        (0,0)
            node[npn](Q1){}
        (Q1.E)
            to [R=$R_E$] ++(0,-2.5)
            node[ground](G){}
        ;
        \draw[color=red]
        (Q1.E)
            to[short,*-] ++ (2,0) node(C){}
            to[C] (C |- G) 
            node[ground]{}
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

**OPTIONAL:**

Using the two nodenames available from the first ground and the second, and drawing from the second ground to the emiter...

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[american]
        \draw
        (0,0)
            node[npn](Q1){}
        (Q1.E)
            to [R=$R_E$] ++(0,-2.5)
            node[ground](G1){}
        ;
        \draw[color=red]
        (G1)++(2,0)
            node[ground](G2){}
            to[C] (G2 |- Q1.E) 
            to[short,-*] (Q1.E)
        ;
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: This is more elegant than my solution because the ground level is labelled (and I'll use it), but still need to use a coordinate (`node(C){}` and `\coordinate(C)` I think are the same thing). Thanks anyway, this is a good idea.

Comment: This coordinate is needed to calculate the intersection to put the ground at the same x position of the first, the other option is using shftings, but writing shiftx=Some_value in a coordinate is not elegant, but I'll try another method to avoid declare the node(C){}...

Comment: I was toying with the `[turn]` coordinate system, but no joy, still relative... ;-)

Comment: Check the optional code...

Comment: Yes, it works... although in the end I prefer your first code. Thanks! I'll wait a bit to see if something magic happens... ;-)

Answer (score 2):

Here is an alternative, but I would not call it simpler.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) node[npn](Q1){};
        \draw (Q1.E) to[R=$R_E$] (0,-2.5) node[ground]{};
        \draw [gray] (Q1.E) -- ++(2,0) \pgfextra{\pgfgetlastxy{\xlast}{\ylast}}
            to[C, color=gray]  (\xlast,-2.5)
            node[ground, color=gray]{};
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Answer (score 1):

Very similar to John Kormylo's answer but without `\pgfextra` (which may cause serious trouble). Similar to John, I am not sure this is more elegant.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\tikzset{magic xy/.code n args={2}{\pgfgetlastxy{#1}{#2}}}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) node[npn](Q1){};
        \draw (Q1.E) to[R=$R_E$] (0,-2.5) node[ground]{};
        \draw [gray] (Q1.E) -- ++(2,0) [magic xy={\magicx}{\magicy}]
            to[C, color=gray]  (\magicx,-2.5)
            node[ground, color=gray]{};
\end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```

Or with calc. Both reproduce your picture.

```
\documentclass[border=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\usetikzlibrary{calc}
\begin{document}
\begin{circuitikz}[american]
        \draw (0,0) node[npn](Q1){};
        \draw (Q1.E) to[R=$R_E$] (0,-2.5) node[ground]{};
        \draw[gray]  let \p1=(Q1.E) in (Q1.E)  -- ++ (2,0) 
             to[C, color=gray]  (\x1+2cm,-2.5)  node[ground, color=gray]{};
            node[ground, color=gray]{};
 \end{circuitikz}
\end{document}
```