# Tikz - Overlapping arrows make them too big

Tags: tikz-arrows

I'm pretty new to Tikz and I'm facing a little issue.

I'd like to draw arrows that are overlapping, all going in same directions, but it's getting wider and wider and is pretty horrible. How could I face it ? Here is the code :

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.3cm]
    % Style
    \tikzstyle{cell} = [rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!20]
    \tikzstyle{tensor} = [circle, minimum width=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!10]

    \tikzstyle{arrow} = [thick,->,>=stealth]

    % Nodes

    \node (he)   [tensor] {$h^e$};

    \node (d1)   [cell, right of=he, below of=he, xshift=1.5cm, yshift=-2cm] {$d$};
    \node (d2)   [cell, right of=d1, xshift=1.5cm] {$d$};
    \node (dn)   [cell, right of=d2, xshift=2cm] {$d$};

    \node (w1)   [tensor, above of=d1, left of=d1, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_1$};
    \node (w2)   [tensor, above of=d2, left of=d2, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_2$};
    \node (wn)   [tensor, above of=dn, left of=dn, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_n$};


    % Arrows
    \draw[arrow] (w1) -| (d1);
    \draw[arrow] (w2) -| (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (wn) -| (dn);

    \draw[arrow] (d1) -- (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (he) |- (d1);

    \draw[arrow] (he) -| (d1);
    \draw[arrow] (he) -| (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (he) -| (dn);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

If you render the figure, you'll see arrows getting darker, how can I fix it ?

Thanks,
Cheers

Comment: Welcome to TeX.Stackexchange! Can you make your example compilable? When I try to run your code I get errors. I can debug them, but how would I know if this still reproduces the problem you are asking about?

Comment: Actually, as I know, if two lines overlapping each other in TikZ, they are darkened.

Comment: @samcarter I fixed it, bad copy/paster my bad

Comment: @joulev That's exactly my problem, I don't want arrows being darkened

Comment: Have you tried to print it? There are often aliasing problems with PDF viewers, and the line can seems darker or not depending on the zoom level.

Comment: @Rmano You're right, when I zoom there's no difference. But it's a numerical report so the "pdf view" issue is actually an issue. I can't print it right now, I'll try.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The following example uses the `calc` library to print each line only once. If you still experience problems with varying line widths this is most probably an issue of your pdf viewer.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows, calc}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.3cm]
    % Style
    \tikzset{
        cell/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!20}, 
        tensor/.style={circle, minimum width=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!10}, arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
        arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
    }

    % Nodes

    \node (he)   [tensor] {$h^e$};

    \node (d1)   [cell, right of=he, below of=he, xshift=1.5cm, yshift=-2cm] {$d$};
    \node (d2)   [cell, right of=d1, xshift=1.5cm] {$d$};
    \node (dn)   [cell, right of=d2, xshift=2cm] {$d$};

    \node (w1)   [tensor, above of=d1, left of=d1, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_1$};
    \node (w2)   [tensor, above of=d2, left of=d2, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_2$};
    \node (wn)   [tensor, above of=dn, left of=dn, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_n$};


    % Arrows
    \draw[arrow] (w1) -| (d1);
    \draw[arrow] (w2) -| (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (wn) -| (dn);

    \draw[arrow] (d1) -- (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (he) |- (d1);

    \draw[arrow] (he) -| (d1);
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (he), \p2 = (d1) in (\x2,\y1) -| (d2);
    \draw[arrow] let \p1 = (he), \p2 = (d2) in (\x2,\y1) -| (dn);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Thanks to @marmot for suggesting this `calc` free version:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{tikz}
\usetikzlibrary{shapes.geometric, arrows}

\begin{document}
    \begin{tikzpicture}[node distance=2.3cm]
    % Style
    \tikzset{
        cell/.style={rectangle, minimum width=1.5cm, minimum height=1.5cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!20}, 
        tensor/.style={circle, minimum width=1cm, text centered, draw=black, fill=green!10}, arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth},
        arrow/.style={thick,->,>=stealth}
    }

    % Nodes

    \node (he)   [tensor] {$h^e$};

    \node (d1)   [cell, right of=he, below of=he, xshift=1.5cm, yshift=-2cm] {$d$};
    \node (d2)   [cell, right of=d1, xshift=1.5cm] {$d$};
    \node (dn)   [cell, right of=d2, xshift=2cm] {$d$};

    \node (w1)   [tensor, above of=d1, left of=d1, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_1$};
    \node (w2)   [tensor, above of=d2, left of=d2, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_2$};
    \node (wn)   [tensor, above of=dn, left of=dn, minimum width=1.25cm] {$w_n$};


    % Arrows
    \draw[arrow] (w1) -| (d1);
    \draw[arrow] (w2) -| (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (wn) -| (dn);

    \draw[arrow] (d1) -- (d2);
    \draw[arrow] (he) |- (d1);

    \draw[arrow] (he) -| (d1);
        \draw[arrow] (d1|-he) -| (d2); 
        \draw[arrow] (d2|-he) -| (dn);

\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, you're awsome ! Could you give a bit background or give some resources so I understand how to reuse this kind of things ?

Comment: @Ricocotam See https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/18393/36296 for a short example how the calc library works

Comment: @marmot Thanks for your suggestions! I just fixed the `\tikzset` and will soon post a second example without calc.

Answer (score 2):

This is what I see (`okular`) at 100% zoom:

[image]

so I can't see any "darkening". Now, zooming in:

[image]

This is a rendering/aliasing problem for subpixel zooms, and it is mostly unsolvable (it depends on the anti-aliasing algorithm of the viewer).