# Drawing NOT-OR gate in LaTeX

Tags: circuitikz, circuits

I want to modify this circuit by aligning the inputs `x_3`, `x_1` and `x_2` on the same vertical line and placing the left black disc on the intersection of `x_1` and the `and` gate.

```
    \begin{circuitikz}
            \node[and port] (A) at (0, 0) {};
            \node at (A) [ocirc,fill=black] {};
            \node[left] at (A.in 1) {\(x_1\)};
            \node[left] at (A.in 2) {\(x_2\)};
            
            \node at (A.bin 1) [ocirc,fill=black] {};
            \node[or port] (B) at (2.7,-0.28) {};
            \node (in3) at ($(B.in 2) - (3, 0)$) {};
            \draw (in3) -- (B.in 2);
            \node at (in3)  {\(x_3\)};
            \node[right] at (B.out) {\((x_1'x_2)'+x_3\)};
            
            \draw (A.out)  --  (B.in 1);
        \end{circuitikz}
```

This produces this

[image]

But I want this

[image]

How do I also make the inverter symbol a black disc instead of a circle?

Comment: For the inverter, just use `\node at (A) [ocirc,fill=black] {};`. For the rest of the question, I didn't understand exactly what you want. Maybe if you drew a sketch of it?

Comment: https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/583841/how-can-i-make-my-logic-circuits-look-better/583867#583867

Comment: If you don't mind deforming the gate slightly you could try `\node[and port, yscale=0.75] (A) at (0, 0) {};`. This scales the y dimensions of the gate by 0.75 times which is enough that there is no overlap and the circuit is still mostly the same.

Comment: yes. It slightly deforms the `x_3` input

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Maybe this? But you may be more specific about what you need.

[image: circuit v1]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
        \node[and port, number inputs=1] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node at (A) [ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 1) {\(x_1\)};
        \node[left] at (A.in 2) {\(x_2\)};
        
        \node[or port] (B) at (4,0.28) {};
        \node[left] at (B.in 1) {\(x_3\)};
        \node[right] at (B.out) {\((x_1'x_2)'+x_3\)};
        
        \draw (A.out)  --  (B.in 2);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

### EDIT

So maybe this one?

[image: V2]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
        \node[and port, number inputs=1] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node at (A) [ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 1) {\(x_1\)};
        \node at (A.left) [yshift=8pt,ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 2) {\(x_2\)};
        
        \node[or port] (B) at (3,-.65) {};
        \node[left] at (B.in 2-| A.in 1) (x3) {\(x_3\)};
        \node[right] at (B.out) {\((x_1'x_2)'+x_3\)};
        
        \draw (A.out)  --++ (1,0) |-  (B.in 1);
        \draw (x3)  --  (B.in 2);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

### SECOND EDIT

Following OP's demand, I propose another evolution of the solution, but it's now mandatory to scale the OR gate a bit.

[image: V3]

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{circuitikz}
\begin{document}

\begin{circuitikz}
        \node[and port, number inputs=1] (A) at (0, 0) {};
        \node at (A) [ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 1) {\(x_1\)};
        \node at (A.in 1) [xshift=6.5pt,ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node at (A.left) [yshift=8pt,ocirc,fill=black] {};
        \node[left] at (A.in 2) {\(x_2\)};
        
        \node[or port,scale=1.2] (B) at (3,-.35) {};
        \node[left] at (B.in 2-| A.in 1) (x3) {\(x_3\)};
        \node[right] at (B.out) {\((x_1'x_2)'+x_3\)};
        
        \draw (A.out)  -- (B.in 1);
        \draw (x3)  --  (B.in 2);
    \end{circuitikz}

\end{document}
```

Comment: I want `x_1,x_2` and `x_3` to be on the same vertical line

Comment: I edited my answer to add this feature. But you can't align x1 x2 and x3 vertically without using a fork link between the two gates (it would end in having x2 and x3 crashed).

Comment: after searching for so long, I found an image that could describe my need. I have updated my requirements. Sorry for this trouble.

Comment: And so I edited my answer once again. Hope it will nicely fit your needs, even if I don't really understand why the fork link seems to bother you like this ;)

Comment: There's no problem with the fork line. Actually I'm learning in this way how to manipulate lines and gaps like this.