# Accessing element in coordinate

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have a list of coordinates defined in a loop. For every coordinate, I would like to draw two circles just off the coordinate. So if my chosen coordinate were A = (x0,y0), it would look like this:

`\draw[fill] ({x0-.1*cos(30)}, {y0-.1*sin(30)} ) circle[radius=.1cm]`

`\draw[fill] ({x0+.1*cos(30)}, {y0+.1*sin(30)} ) circle[radius=.1cm]`

But I don't know how to access x0 or y0 (i.e. in python I would write A[0] and A[1]). Hope it makes sense.

Comment: [Welcome to TeX.SX!](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/1436) Please help us help you and add a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that illustrates your problem. Reproducing the problem and finding out what the issue is will be much easier when we see compilable code, starting with `\documentclass{...}` and ending with `\end{document}`.

Comment: This looks a lot like [this question](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/18389/tikz-node-at-same-x-coordinate-as-another-node-but-specified-y-coordinate) Could one of the answers there be useful to you?

Comment: Yes, thank you! One of those answers was exactly what I was looking for!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your question is very light on details (and in particular a MWE), so I must assume that this is what you mean:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{tikz}
\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
  \coordinate (A) at (1,2);
  \draw[fill] (A) ++({-.1*cos(30)},{-.1*sin(30)}) circle[radius=.1cm];
  \draw[fill] (A) ++({+.1*cos(30)},{+.1*sin(30)}) circle[radius=.1cm];
\end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Comment: Yes that's precisely what I meant. Thank you!!